# How to convert wchar_t to multi-bytes char in C

Tags: c, encoding, type-conversion, wchar, multibyte-characters

I'm looking for a way to convert wchar_t to multi-bytes char, *without* using wctomb or any ready-made routine. I have to do that in C, not C++, and the interoperability doesn't matter here.

My goal is to print wchar byte by byte using the write syscall. For example, the 'é' character is equivalent to 0xe9 encoded into a wchar, and is equivalent to `ff ff ff c3` `ff ff ff a9` in its multi-bytes form. Ho can I switch from one form to the other?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I'm looking for a way to convert wchar_t to multi-bytes char, without using wctomb` Do you know the encoding used to store `wchar_t` and the encoding used for multibyte string?

Comment: No, I don't know the encoding used, how can I find that? I'm on Debian, using gcc.

Comment: `using gcc`  Read it's documentation. `or any ready-made routine` Would be extremely hard.

Comment: It's for a school project, so I guess is not that hard once you know the trick.

Comment: It very much sounds as if you are expected to do a UTF-32 (aka UCS-4) to UTF-8 conversion. That's straight-forward to implement.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a way to convert wchar_t to multi-bytes char, without using wctomb or any ready-made routine

This is the same as conversion between any two encodings. First determine the encoding used to encode characters in source and destination, then translate characters from one encoding to another.

So first `wchar_t` - it's encoding is (or should be) constant and determined by your compiler and environment. So read about your environment and about your compiler. You specified `Debian, using gcc` then read [gcc documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Extended-Char-Intro.html) and nowadays **on linux** `wchar_t` is meant to represent [one `UCS-4` "character"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Coded_Character_Set). Note that on windows `wchar_t` is `UTF-16`.

Then determine the destination encoding, the encoding of the multi-byte string - it depends on [locale](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale). Read and parse `LC_CTYPE` locale, you might want read [posix locale](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html) and about [locale naming](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locale-Names.html). Then because of `without using any ready-made routine` in the sad case when the locale doesn't specify `codeset`, you have to write your own platform-specific parser for `locale` specific files and infer the default character encoding for specific current locale (I am not really sure how it happens here, you have to find "the locale language category"). Pages like [man 7 locale](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html) [man 7 charsets](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/charsets.7.html) look like a good read.

Then after determining the destination and source encodings, you need to write a routine that will translate one encoding to another. Because of `without using any ready-made routine` you don't want to use [iconv](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/iconv.html), that means you have to write it yourself. That goes to reading specification of both encodings and what characters are represents by what [codepoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) in these encodings and then deciding how to translate each and every codepoint from one encoding to another.

All in all, another projects source code, like [glibc source code](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/locale/programs/localedef.c) or [libiconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) or [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/) might be sources of inspiration.

> It's for a school project, so I guess is not that hard once you know the trick.

*Most probably* the multibyte encoding is UTF-8, unicode is dominating todays world. As such, you'll want to research how to convert a UTF-32 to UTF-8, which is actually a simple routine.